# How to carriage return ('\r') when printing a string with an std::endl at the end of it?

Tags: c++, spdlog

In C++, I am using spdlog to print important information for my code to help me debug it. However, I don't want a specific message to be printed every line every frame, I want it to be over-printed with the new message just like using '\r'. So the problem is I think spdlog uses '\n' or std::endl for every message it logs and I don't want that because it prevents me from using '\r' to override the printed string and print another, how can I fix this?

I tried doing `std::cout << '\r';` before/after the spdlog message but it just won't work. I'm mostly sure it's because of the new-line character but have no idea how to fix it..

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: Have you tried searching spdlog issues for this? https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/2378

Comment: Standard C++ stream I/O doesn't work the way you are looking for. There is no guarantee that a bare `'\r'` will go back to the beginning of the current line. That is a function of the terminal. You need platform APIs or an ncurses-like library to get the kind of output control you are looking for.

Comment: If the log is going to a file, using `\r` won't move the file write position backwards to just after the previous newline — that could only happen if you display the data to a terminal, and even then, it isn't reliably what you'd see.  So, even if you can set the EOL characters when building spdlog, it is unlikely to do what you're after, if I'm interpreting what you want correctly.

Comment: Yeah, trying to use a library with a name that sounds like it's specifically meant for logging to do this kind of screen manipulation... not a good idea. Still, from the looks of it, you don't need that to be portable -- just print to std::cout yourself and do whatever works for you. I actually do that a lot for debugging -- when I look at commit diffs before committing, seeing messages sent to std::cout means it's something I forgot to remove.

Comment: Logs are meant to be kept for later analysis. So just don't do that.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You're saying you have already written a log line, but based on some condition that comes later, undo that event.  **That's not a normal pattern.**  It sounds like to me what you really want to do is just defer the log statement until you're sure all conditions are in place to do it. Otherwise, write something else (or nothing at all).

Comment: Your question never mentions *where* you are printing these messages. That is relevant, since different destinations behave differently. Presumably, you mean a terminal of some sort, but note that there is nothing in your question inconsistent with printing to a printer. *(In fact, a printer would do a better job of "over-printed" since the lines would be superimposed -- this was probably not a good word choice to describe what you meant.)* Which terminal (or printer) are you using?

Comment: @Quimby The link you provided has the answer I was searching for, thanks a lot! <3